# Apply function with pandas dataframe - POS tagger computation time

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pos-tagger

I'm very confused on the apply function for pandas. I have a big dataframe where one column is a column of strings. I'm then using a function to count part-of-speech occurrences. I'm just not sure the way of setting up my apply statement or my function.

```
def noun_count(row):
    x = tagger(df['string'][row].split())
    # array flattening and filtering out all but nouns, then summing them
    return num
```

So basically I have a function similar to the above where I use a POS tagger on a column that outputs a single number (number of nouns). I may possibly rewrite it to output multiple numbers for different parts of speech, but I can't wrap my head around `apply`.

I'm pretty sure I don't really have either part arranged correctly. For instance, I can run `noun_count[row]` and get the correct value for any index but I can't figure out how to make it work with apply how I have it set up. Basically I don't know how to pass the row value to the function within the apply statement.

```
df['num_nouns'] = df.apply(noun_count(??),1)
```

Sorry this question is all over the place. So what can I do to get a simple result like

```
      string     num_nouns
0      'cat'             1
1 'two cats'             1
```

EDIT:
So I've managed to get something working by using list comprehension (someone posted an answer, but they've deleted it).

```
df['string'].apply(lambda row: noun_count(row),1)
```

which required an adjustment to my function:

```
def tagger_nouns(x):
    list_of_lists = st.tag(x.split())
    flat = [y for z in list_of_lists for y in z]
    Parts_of_speech = [row[1] for row in flattened]
    c = Counter(Parts_of_speech)
    nouns = c['NN']+c['NNS']+c['NNP']+c['NNPS']
    return nouns
```

I'm using the Stanford tagger, but I have a big problem with computation time, and I'm using the left 3 words model. I'm noticing that it's calling the .jar file again and again (java keeps opening and closing in the task manager) and maybe that's unavoidable, but it's really taking far too long to run. Any way I can speed it up?

Comment: Hey, that was me, I deleted b/c I couldn't tell if the answer was useful.  I put it back although you have integrated it at this point anyway.

Comment: Rather than expanding this question (somewhat discouraged here), I think you might get more help reposting the additional stuff as a new (and briefer) question along the lines of 'how can I make this faster?'  I'd also recommend being explicit about what 'tagger' is -- how does one import it?  is it part of standard library?  etc.  I don't think most folks looking and pandas tags will know what it is and that makes it hard to answer.

Comment: Just did a quick search on 'tagger'.  Is it part of nltk?  If so, definitely add that as a tag (or whatever library it is from) when you make a new question.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what 'tagger' is but here's a simple example with a word count that ought to work more or less the same way:

```
f = lambda x: len(x.split())

df['num_words'] = df['string'].apply(f)

       string  num_words
0       'cat'          1
1  'two cats'          2
```